# Processing stop the animation

Tags: java, processing

I have the following code (in Processing Software) which I want to stop the particles before they leave the screen… 
So I dont know how to stop them near the edges of the screen…

Please advice…

Thanks

```
    Particle [] pickles = new Particle [100];


void setup () {

  size (500, 500);
  smooth ();
  for (int i=0; i<pickles.length; i++) {
    pickles [i] = new Particle ();
  }
}


void draw () {
  background (0); //clear the background

  for (int i=0; i<pickles.length; i++) {
    pickles[i].update();
  }
}

class Particle {

  float x;
  float y;

  float velX ; // speed or velocity
  float velY;


  Particle () {
    //x and y position to be in middle of screen
    x = width/2;
    y = height/2;

    velX = random (-10, 10);
    velY = random (-10, 10);

} 

  void update () {

    x+=velX;
    y+=velY;

    fill (255);
    ellipse (x, y, 10, 10);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't tag your question with all those language tags- you're going to attract a ton of downvotes. Also please be more specific: what do you want to do when the particles hit the edge of the screen?

Comment: Sorry about that..If they bounce back from the edges, that would be great. But somehow, I cant control them after explosion..

Comment: Try `if (x+velX > 0 && x+velX < width && y+velY > 0 && y+velY < height) { x+=velX; y+=velY; }`

Comment: Please link between crossposts. This question has also been posted here: https://discourse.processing.org/t/stop-the-explosion/5071

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether a particle is going outside the bounds of the screen by comparing its `x` and `y` values to the screen dimensions. For example:

```
if(x < 0){
  // particle is off left edge of screen
}
else if(x > width){
  // particle is off right edge of screen
}
```

When you detect one of these conditions, you can do a number of things:

- Remove the particle from the array so it stops using system resources after it leaves the screen
- Wrap the value around to the other side of the screen
- Have it bounce off the edge by reversing its velocity

Which approach you take depends on exactly what you want to happen.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection) is a tutorial on collision detection in Processing, which includes the above approaches.